# How to resolve unicode issue with javascript length?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, unicode

I have angular tooltip for character counter but here i am facing some issues when user copy paste text and add some `ascii` characters that are not aligned with the java and orcale length when we post the data to the backend, Lets say if user have @ in the text it will count lenght as 1 but backend side it will count as 4 because of the way oracle and java works with bytes.
So i am trying to resolve two issues.

1- when i paste text it character counter should count same unicode as java ?

2- It should not remove characters from the text ?

main.html

```
<textarea rows="2" class="form-control"
    ng-model="processDTO.processStatementText"
    name="processStatement" id="processStatement"
    placeholder="Process Statement" maxlength="4000" required
    data-tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>{{4000 - processDTO.processStatementText.length}} characters left</div>"
    tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'focus', false: 'never'}[processDTO.processStatementText.length >= 0 || processDTO.processStatementText.length == null ]}}"
    tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-class="bluefill">
</textarea>
```

main.txt

```
2.  Upload Template Header – Risk Causal and Impact comments are color coded as mandatory but they are optional. Similary the Originating Source System Process/Risk/control ID
3.  In the upload template, for any of the multi value fields, I use an invalid delimiter ‘:’, Eg: 13:7 , for some reason this changes the cell format to time format and thereafter I am not able to give any single values, its always converted to time format. Not sure if this is a training issue, but want to put it on the table to see if it requires any fix at all
4.  In Upload, for the grid field length validations, the filter doesn’t works on Row Number and Max Allowed columns. ~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+|}{:&quot;?&gt;&lt;,./&#39;;[]\=-0987654321`
5.  ERH All levels added in the View End to End ERH screen – Sort and Filter doesn’t works, After clicking on this field, none of the other filter/sort works on the page. Also the sort indicator(black triangle) is not visible, I believe the column width needs to be adjusted.
6.  The Risk/Control reference id is seen on the Process Search grids, but when I search by Risk/Control, I don’t see the corresponding control/risk grid having the ref id column however tool tip has it
7.  The label change “Originating Source System Process/Risk/Control ID”"
```

Comment: I think you need to inspect each character and look for multibyte characters. This answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057534/javascript-encoding-breaking-combining-multibyte-characters

Comment: any example how can i fix with code above with angularJs ?

Comment: `@` is plain ASCII and is stored as one byte in almost all encodings (the exceptions being UTF-16 and UTF-32, but it seems unlikely you'd be working with four-byte UTF-32). Why do you say it counts as 4?

Comment: thats what backend developer explain it to me that is being passed as 4 bytes to database.